# Best way to place a larger UIView inside smaller one by scaling the larger one to fit

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I am grabbing a screen shot (as UIView object) of the view of my next controller and would like to place that screenshot inside a small rectangle in my preceeding controller's view (like a preview). What is the best way to place a large UIView object inside smaller one?

This did not work:

```
UIView *screenshot = .... // screenshot from the next controller's view
smallViewBox.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
[smallViewBox addSubView:screenshot];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the bounds of the larger view to match the bounds of the smaller one. I just whipped up a quick example:

```
UIView *largeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 60, 60)];
largeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:largeView];

UIView *smallView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,40,40)];
smallView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:smallView];

largeView.bounds = smallView.bounds;
```

If you comment out the largeView.bounds = smallView.bounds the green (smaller) box will be the only one visible because it is being drawn over the red box in the controller's view (The two views are siblings in this instance). To make the larger view a subview of the smaller one and restrict it to the smaller one's area you can do this:

```
UIView *largeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 60, 60)];
largeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIView *smallView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,40,40)];
smallView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:smallView];

largeView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, smallView.bounds.size.width, smallView.bounds.size.height);
[smallView addSubview:largeView];
```

This will result in the larger view's red color visible - covering the green smaller view's background. In this instance the large view is a child of the small view and occupies its entire area.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a scale transform on it.

```
screenshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: Karah, your answer is correct in the sense that it scales the UIView, however, when I add it to smaller view, it appears off the box somewhere down below. I think I would need a few tun-ups to make your version work. GWhite's answer worked flawlessly so I am accepting his answer but giving yours an upvote for another correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Appreciated.  I agree GWhite's answer is much more accurate.  Using the scale transform would require you to do some math depending on the  UIView.

Comment: I actually I made it work with transform, I accurately scaled it as well while maintaining aspect ratio. I just had to change the origin of screenshot to (0,0). So, yours works too. Thanks again